# Making a class for storing numbers of my project

Tags: java

I have game project similar to chicken invaders with java swing . i want to save some numbers or dimensions for my project for using them all over the project . For example , i build my `spaceShip` with width equal to one fifth of the main frame . but i don't want to call `mainFrame.getWidth()`every time and divide it by 5 ; so i am building a class to store these numbers , for example `spaceShip` size and starting position an so on . The question is , is it better to create a singleton class and get an instance every time i want a number , or build a class with static fields of numbers i want . I provide the code for both of them.

first way:

```
public class Dimensions {
    private static GameObjects gameObjects = GameObjects.create();//a singleton class i keep my obj
    final public static int spaceShipHeight =   gameObjects.getMainFrame().getHeight()/8
            , spaceShipWidth = gameObjects.getMainFrame().getWidth()/15 ;

    private Dimensions() {
    }
}
```

second way:

```
public class Dimensions {
    Dimensios dimensions;
    int spaceShipHeight , spaceShipWidth ;

    private Dimensions() {
        int spaceShipHeight = gameObjects.getMainFrame().getHeight()/8;
                int spaceShipWidth = gameObjects.getMainFrame().getHeight()/15;
    }
    public Dimensions create() {
        if(dimensions==null) {
            dimensions = new Dimensions();
        }
        return dimension;
    }

        // and here goes the code for getters 
        public int getSpaceShipHeight(){
           return spaceShipHeight;
        }
}
```

and for using:
first way : `int a  = Dimensions.spaceShipHeight;`
second way : `int a = Dimensions.getSpaceShipHeight();`

edit :
I have the same question for building a class to keep my pictures . 
Does the answer differ here?

Comment: For constants which are global for all your application and not changable in time of run it's better to use class with set of `static final` values. Also `enum` type could be convenient here.

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski and what for using them . Should i use getters or use them like the first way?

Comment: No need for getter if value is `static final`.